# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My spring boot test is throwing the below error during maven build.

```
"level":"ERROR","logger":"com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig","msg":"HikariPool-1 - jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName."
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource
[com/pit/SchedulerConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is requir
ed with driverClassName.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
```

The method that throws an error in my MyApplicationTest.java

```
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = MyConfig.class)
class MyApplicationTest {

   @Test
   void contextLoads() {
   assertNotNull(myController);

   }
}
```

My pom has these dependencies in classpath.

- spring-boot-starter-web
- spring-boot-starter-test
- spring-integration-sftp
- postgresql
- junit
- quartz-scheduler

My Datasource bean is configured as below

```
@Configuration
public class MyDataSourceCfg {

  private DataSource appDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
          .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
          .url(env.getProperty("url") // values are set from Environment
          .username(env.getProperty("user"))
          .password(env.getProperty("password")
          .build();
  }
}
```

Please tell me what is happening and how I avoid this error. I read about configuring Datasource in different way in case you have multiple database but I just have one postgres database. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: `.url(env.getProperty("url")` seems not to hold a JDBC URL "jdcb: ...". The error often resides at the line with a comment.

Comment: @JoopEggen The properties are pulled from a vault and put in Environment during start up. "jdbc:postgresql://..." is how I've configured it. I'm able to start the app and run, if I skip tests during build.

Comment: Maybe the unit tests have a different configuration? Spring often has an application context and an application context test. And test often go against a different database.

Comment: `[ERROR] contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
` what I can see just above the stack error. Have put the test class in the question. There is nothing else in the class apart from one other autowired beans.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help there.  You could start with hard-coded strings: `.url("jdbc: ...")`, and logging.

Comment: Thank you @JoopEggen for the support

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have all relevant dependencies.
as Connect to PostgreSQL Database with Spring Data JPA such as :-

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and in `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dev
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect
```

With SpringBoot's powerful autoconfiguration, you don't need to explicitly create a DataSource bean and if in case you want, use these properties values.

Comment: I could use this if I can know how to access properties from Environment class in application yaml file since all the values are put to Enrvironment map during startup from a different source. Also to note, the issue is resolved when I hardcoded the details.